# Mapping arbitrary unicode characters?

Tags: key-bindings, unicode

I want to create a mapping that is ctrl+[some obscure unicode character], how can I do this for terminal vim using the actual unicode code?

Backstory: I'm trying to work around i3wm, where ctrl+hjkl would sometimes be handled by i3wm and sometimes passed to vim with xdotool, but once something is mapped in i3wm it will always catch it, so instead I want to send a very obscure keypress via xdotool so it doesn't actually take up a useful mapping, which one might actually want to type with a keyboard, but does what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `:h <Char>`

To map a character by its decimal, octal or hexadecimal number the 
construct can be used:

```
<Char-123>      character 123
<Char-033>      character 27
<Char-0x7f>     character 127
<S-Char-114>    character 114 ('r') shifted ('R')
```

This is useful to specify a (multibyte) character in a 'keymap' file.
Upper and lowercase differences are ignored.